# Django error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, django, admin

I was using both EmbeddedModelFields and ListFields in Django's admin. To do so, I'm using the following tutorials:
https://gist.github.com/jonashaag/1200165
https://gist.github.com/ielshareef/3011156

My models.py contains the following,

```
class EmbedOverrideField(EmbeddedModelField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return models.Field.formfield(self, ObjectListField, **kwargs)

class CategoryField(ListField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return models.Field.formfield(self, StringListField, **kwargs)

class Post(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) # 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post_text = models.TextField()
    tags = CategoryField()
    comments = CategoryField(EmbedOverrideField('Comment'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_text
```

And in admin.py I have,

```
site.register(Post)
```

On the admin site, I tried clicking on "Post" to see what's there, and I get the above error. Why might this be?

Thank you!

EDIT: I don't know if this is of any help but when I try to add a new Post, I see a form into which I can enter a post title, text, tags, and comments. When I actually save it, I get the error,

```
Expected instance of type <class 'polls.models.Comment'>, not <type 'unicode'>.
```

And just to be clear, I am indeed using MongoDB as my backend.

The following is the full exception stack trace:

```
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,      **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  466.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args,    **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
1445.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt':  len(cl.result_list)},
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
77.         self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
857.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in results_iter
381.             yield self._make_result(entity, fields)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py" in _make_result
431.                 value = self.ops.value_from_db(value, field)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in value_from_db
254.         return self._value_from_db(value, *self._convert_as(field))
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py" in _value_from_db
154.             value, field, field_kind, db_type)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in _value_from_db
380.                                                    field_kind, db_type)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in _value_from_db_collection
513.                 return list(value)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in <genexpr>
508.                 for subvalue in value) 
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/django_mongodb_engine/base.py" in _value_from_db
154.             value, field, field_kind, db_type)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in _value_from_db
385.                                               field_kind, db_type)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/base.py" in _value_from_db_model
587.         embedded_model = field.stored_model(value)
File "/Users/Anupa/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/fields.py" in stored_model
299.         module = column_values.pop('_module', None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/polls/post/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Comment: Can you share the full exception stack trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you forgot the Comment model ?

Edit:

The issue was there was a Post entity with comment as string instead of Comment instance.

Comment: No, I have my model for comment in models.py. I just didn't show it.

Comment: Ow... Check what's already stored in mongo for POSTS. You may have an object that it's a string instead of comment...

Comment: I posted above. The issue was, as you mentioned, that I saved a Post object with a string as a comment. Go ahead and update the answer. :-)

Comment: Curiosity though. How did it end up with string instead of Comment ? Old record ?

Comment: Yep! Just an old record. I was initially storing comments as strings, but I chose to switch to another model. Completely forgot that I did this. So silly!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error by calling,

```
from polls.models import Post
Post.objects.get()
```

I fixed it by switching to a brand new database. My error with posting comments still persists, though. :-( Any idea how to fix that one?